# Register/Login from android using oauth2 and google API

Tags: android

Working on a native app that requires the user to register to our server.
I would like the user to be able to use oauth2 with google contact api to login.
Not knowing exactly how this would work but idea is:

get default google account and get a token. 
send relevant data to our server.(token/userinfo) 
verify google account on server and create a one time password 
send password to phone 
let user register to our service with google account name and one time password

I am not really sure how to do this and what type of token / authorization code I need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project describing the use of [oAuth](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidOauthGoogleApiJavaClient).